# Transpose of composite functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, function-and-relation-composition

I want to prove that $(gof)^T$=$f^Tog^T$ where $f,g$ are linear maps.

I know that I can just use definitions but I don't know exactly how. Can anyone point me in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a linear form, and $v$ a vector (on/in appropriate vector spaces) then
$$
  (g\circ f)^T(\alpha)(v)
 =\alpha((g\circ f)(v))
 =\alpha(g(f(v)))
 =g^T(\alpha)(f(v))
 =f^T(g^T(\alpha))(v)
 =(f^T\circ g^T)(\alpha)(v),
$$
and since this holds for all $\alpha,v$, one has $(g\circ f)^T=f^T\circ g^T$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : V \to W$, $g : W \to U$, then $f^T : W^* \to V^*$, $g^T : U^* \to W^*$.

$f^T$ is defined by $$\langle f^T x,y\rangle = \langle x, f y\rangle$$ for all $x,y$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ denotes the appropriate duality pairing, and I will leave it implicit that $x \in W^*, y \in V$, etc., so that the LHS is the duality in $V$, the RHS is the duality in $W$, etc.

Try starting by writing $\langle (g\circ f)^T x,y \rangle$, and then applying the definitions to show this is equal to $ \langle  f^Tg^Tx,y\rangle$. Since you do this for arbitrary $x,y$, this proves what you want.

Explicitly:

> $$\langle (g\circ f)^T x,y \rangle = \langle x,(g \circ f)y\rangle = \langle  g^Tx,fy\rangle = \langle  f^Tg^Tx,y\rangle$$